# Are fullerenes a capable/reliable "part" for my microorganism to work?

Tags: science-based, xenobiology, chemistry, science-in-society, biochemistry

#### What I need the microorganisms for

They collect and store chemicals, can be manipulated to do what a bigger life form wants. With enough of these microorgansisms and some knowledge of chemistry one could make these reactions work like a bad form "magic" that sucks in comparison to every other "magic system".

The microorganisms are floating and laying around everywhere in huge masses, **looking pretty much like snow**. They don't appear like an ominous wind that helps certain people. Everybody uses them in everyday life. They get bred, charged up and used pretty much all the time. To some point they are even part of most bigger lifeforms, helping out just like bacteria. That could explain, how the "controller species" spoken of could communicate to its small helpers.

The most key purpose of these small organisms is to explain my magic system with few words. "One can control them to trigger any kind of reaction possible with the material they have in store." Used in the right way and (of course) in the right amount (most of the time you need huge amounts), you can make them fly in swarms, lift objects, shoot fire, mix poison and even regenerate bodies. This way there are billions of "magic spells" predefined by science.

#### How the microorganisms anatomy works

Well... Here's the problem. There isn't anything comparable on earth and I don't know much about biology or chemistry. There are many things to explain. A major problem is that many and even very reactive chemicals have to get stored in big amounts, both carefully and efficient at the same time. Also there must be a way to synthesise complex molecules.

In my research I found a molecule called ["fullerene"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fullerene). Being thin and very stable, I thought that they might be a good material to separate stored molecules. This material could even serve as catalyst for (and as a protection against ) exotherme reactions. - these are my assumptions after some research. I also don't know if small life forms could build and destroy this material easily enough.

With all the probability, all the resources and some luck given...

**Can you tell if fullerenes are a capable/reliable way to store and provide chemical elements for my microorganisms to work?**

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding! No need to apologize for your English. Trust me, I've seen *far* worse on this site. If you would like some feedback, for example about your English, before posting your question on the Main site you should check out our [Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4835/28789). You might also be interested in [Why should I register my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557/352819) Registering allows you to keep track of your questions and your reputation if you ever delete your cookies.

Comment: I removed some of your fluff, but I left the part about being embarassed, even if it's unnecessary. Are you sure that's needed for the question? If you are afraid of someone ripping off your idea you should think about maybe restructuring your question to reveal less of your idea (I don't know anything about legal stuff, so I won't comment on that; it's just a bit distracting from the question).If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Comment: Only you can know what is and what isn't worthy of your time. Also, second quotation looks too broad to me.

Comment: This gives me the sense of midichlorians.

Comment: Another tip: to notify another user you have to write an "@" in front of their name. It even autocompletes. You can only notify one user per comment (the OP is always notified) and the user has to have already interacted with your post, for example by writing a comment or editing (in the latter case it won't autocomplete though). I rephrased your title to make it more descriptive of what the question is about as your title didn't fit your question body and sounded opinion-based as @Mołot said, which would be a reason to vote to close this question.

Comment: Okay 2 questions:
1) What is this 'magic' supposed to do? create objects from thin air, generate fire/lightning/..., telekinesis?
These are all different and require different chemistry to work.
2) How much science based do you want this to be? I don't think a complete hard-science answer is possible for most effects - at least not with the science we know. Also how do people (all people, only some?) control this, just 'magic' or again science based?

Comment: I'm unclear how your magic system functions. Apparently, microorganisms store chemicals and other creatures use these organisms/chemicals to perform magic? But _how_ are they used to perform magic? You could handwave it away and say they can use magic because they have these microorganisms, but it feels like you left out a step in the description you provided. Also, as Nicolai said, what magical effects are being produced? We've had a few questions about an organism using microorganisms to generate, for example, fire breath, through biology/chemistry. Is this the same type of thing?

Comment: This sounds like utility fog with micro-organisms instead of nanites or whatever anyone wants to call their nanotechnological things. A utility fog microbiome might answer your question 2.

Comment: As @RonJohn points out, this idea already exists in the *Star Wars* universe (this is so close it might be trademark infringement).  The only difference is you appear to want to explain the chemistry behind "The Force."  Your question has been put on hold as "primarily opinion-based" because no answer can be judged better than any other except by popular vote, which is not acceptable on Stack Exchange sites.  Frankly, your best solution is to invent a word (e.g., "midichlorians") and move forward as, obviously, no known chemical or construct will fulfill the requirements of magic.

Comment: @JBH  "already exists in star wars"?  I'm sorry to call you out for being wrong. My "microorganisms work based on chemical reactions. Chemistry isn't just an explanation to an other stupid concept. In star wars they can read and control others minds with "the force"  How would these "Midichlorians" lift Something up anyway? With "energy"? Energy provided by, *cough* holy lifeforms that just exist without a real reason? Is that an original concept to you? My microorganisms can't do anything like whatever they use in star wars because no matter how hard they try to be magic, they aren't magic.